# I am getting Missing Refrence Exeption when using Destroy() function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a shooting game and I want to set a range for the bullet. That means when it's been shot it flies for a period of time and then it gets destroyed.

I've tried the `Destroy` function; however, the way I've implemented the code looks as though it attempts to destroy the original bullet from the firing point, rather than at the end of it's range.

**here's my code:**

```
if (Input.GetKey("space"))
{
    Instantiate(bullet, transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, 1), bullet.rotation);
    Destroy(bullet, 0.4f);
}
```

It will just fire once then I get `MissingReferenceException`.

Comment: you destroy the prefab. you will need to store the return value of instantiate and call destroy on that.

Comment: thought i wouldnt be lazy today and added it as answer, please tick it as correct for completeness sake :D

Comment: yes i will :D thanks again you solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You destroy the prefab. When you instantiate you get a reference back, thats the actual gameobject you want to destroy.

```
if (Input.GetKey("space"))
{
    GameObject bulletInstance; //or whatever type your bullet is
    bulletInstance = Instantiate(bullet, transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, 1), bullett.rotation);
    Destroy(bulletInstance , 0.4f); //if you instantiated via a component, you have to destroy bulletInstance.gameObject or you'll only destroy the component
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html

Edit: Please note this creates a lot of garbage and was only meant to answer your question, you should consider using object pooling for bullets.
https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/object-pooling